Moving Joystick Up Causes Raspberry Pi Pico to Disconnect
I was following this guide:
https://www.tomshardware.com/how-to/raspberry-pi-pico-joystick
Everything works as described and I'm getting the expected values except for when I move the Joystick up on the Y axis. Then I get this error:

PROBLEM IN THONNY'S BACK-END: Exception while handling 'Run' (ConnectionError: EOF).
See Thonny's backend.log for more info.
You may need to press "Stop/Restart" or hard-reset your MicroPython device and try again.
Process ended with exit code 1.

I have the exact components described in the guide and all my solder joints on the pins are good. If I reset it will work again and return expected values except for Y axis up (any value below neutral which is about 33000).
I've searched for everything I can think of and can't find any mention of this problem from anyone else.  I can't think what it would be.
Here is the program I'm running:
import utime
xAxis = ADC(Pin(27))
yAxis = ADC(Pin(26))
button = Pin(16,Pin.IN, Pin.PULL_UP)
while True:
    xValue = xAxis.read_u16()
    yValue = yAxis.read_u16()
    buttonValue= button.value()
    print(str(xValue) +", " + str(yValue) + " -- " + str(buttonValue))
    utime.sleep(0.1)

But it doesn't matter if a program is running or not.  The second you move the stick up on the Y axis the Pico disconnects.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

You've got a short between the joystick Y output, and the adjacent RUN pin - which resets the Pico when pulled low.

Keep a magnifying glass handy for just such inspections, and an old toothbrush and a drop of 99% isopropyl alcohol for cleaning the solder joints of burned flux. If you find a narrow (or touching) solder joint, heat between the pins with your iron until the solder melts and sweep through the gap with the iron and then follow-up quickly with a toothpick (repeat until working) Clean all joints with the toothbrush with a drop or two of the 99% isopropyl alcohol. After cleaning the alcohol will flash dry in a few seconds. You can use a soft-cotton cloth to remove any left-over residue.

Sorted it.  There was a miniscule filament of wire from a previous project that was shorting the Y axis pin to the adjacent Run pin.  Due to time constraints for this project I had to just switch to a different ADC pin rather than repair the short. After switching pins everything is working great.
